# Mage::getModel instance overriden

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, model, unit-tests

I managed to put up a `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case` with this:

```
public function testGetModelMemoryTrace() {
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product = $model->load(10);
    $this->assertEquals($product->getId(), 10);
    $parentProduct = $model->load(4);
    $this->assertEquals($product->getId(), 10); //here getId() is actually 4...
}
```

This test fails for me in the last assert. Is this an expected effect ? To clarify, the second load alters first reference to object id 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$model->load** doesnt return a new instance. It returns itself. So **$model**, **$product** and **$parentProduct** is actually the same instance.

Comment: exactly, while Mage::getModel('catalog/product') is a factory and returns always a new instance, the ->load() is only a method which returns $this.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is here... 
When you load prroduct at second time the yoy took variable `$parentProduct` and you are passing variable `$product`.

`$product` contain reference of product id 10 and

`$parentProduct` contain reference of product id 4.

Thant's why you are getting 10 as product id at second time. So either need to change `$product->getId()` to `$parentProduct->getId()` or when you are loading product at second time for id 4 then re-assign it to variable `$product`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I intentionally did that to show collateral effect of model loadings. Please run the test and you will understand.

Comment: I understand, you are correct that load doesn't return an instance but look variable $product have data of product id 10 and once its initialized, then even if you change the instance data by loading another product then still variable $product have data which was loaded for product id 10 because it have own memory space. So wherever you use that variable it will always return 10.

Comment: You missed the point that `$model`, `$product`, `$parentProduct` all point to the same object. So you said that once loading product id 10, that will always remain even with another load ? That is not true, because loading product id 4 after 10 changed these three references. Read the other answer and other comment please.

Comment: I never said that they aren't pointing same object. They are pointing same object i know but i am talking about the variables(`$product` and `$parentProduct`) that you are using  to assign every time for different product data.